# Python - Как создать 2d массив из DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть DataFrame типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить такой массив (`list`) ? :

```
[[1, ['Test1',5]],[2, ['Test2',10]],[3, ['Test3',15]]]
```

Comment: В следующий раз приводите пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом формате (текстом), а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример данных:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
    A   B  id
0  aa   5   1
1  bb  10   2
2  cc  15   3
```

решение:

```
res = [[idx, row.to_list()] for idx, row in df.set_index("id").iterrows()]
```

результат:

```
In [30]: res
Out[30]: [[1, ['aa', 5]], [2, ['bb', 10]], [3, ['cc', 15]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res =  [[x[-1],x[:-1].tolist()] for x in df.values]
```

res:

```
[[1, ['Test1', 5]], [2, ['Test2', 10]], [3, ['Test3', 15]]]
```